# Why is GROUP BY clause missing rows

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Can't understand a strange behavior of `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT id, SUM(num) as sum
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 2 AS num UNION
    SELECT 1, 3) AS a
GROUP BY id
```

results in:

```
id  | sum |
----|-----|
1   | 5   |
```

but

```
SELECT id, SUM(num) as sum
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 2 AS num UNION
    SELECT 1, 2 /*!*/) AS a
GROUP BY id
```

results in:

```
id  | sum |
----|-----|
1   | 2   |
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`UNION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) excludes duplicate rows.

You want to use [`UNION ALL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in this example:

```sql
 SELECT id, SUM(num) as sum
 FROM (
     SELECT 1 AS id, 2 AS num UNION ALL
     SELECT 1, 2 /*!*/) AS a
 GROUP BY id
```

Results:

```
id          sum
----------- -----------
1           4
```